# Ambiguous option with boost because the parameter name begins with the same string

Tags: c++, boost, boost-program-options

Here is my problem:

Using program_options from lib BOOST (C++), I have this weird behavior:

```
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
#include <boost/program_options/options_description.hpp>

using namespace boost;
namespace po = boost::program_options;

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int ac,char* av[])
{
  int cost_function_param;
  po::options_description desc("Allowed options");
  desc.add_options()
          ("cost-function", po::value<string>()->default_value("WA"), "Cost function (W: wirelength, A: area ratio, C: cut; [WA, WAC, WC, AC]")
          ("cost-function-param", po::value<int>(&cost_function_param)->default_value(0), "Specify the parameter of the cost function. Implemented is \"C\" only for now.")
          ;
  po::variables_map vm;
  try {
    po::store(po::parse_command_line(ac, av, desc), vm);
    po::notify(vm);
  }
  catch(po::error& e)
  {
    std::cerr << "ERROR: " << e.what() << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::cerr << desc << std::endl;
    return -1;
  }
}
```

Case #1:

```
./Debug/partition --cost-function-param 200
```

No error.

Case #2:

```
./Debug/partition --cost-function-param 2000 --cost-function WAC
```

or

```
./Debug/partition --cost-function WAC
```

results in:

```
ERROR: ambiguous option cost-function

Allowed options:
  --cost-function arg (=WA)      Cost function (W: wirelength, A: area ratio,C: cut; [WA, WAC, WC, AC]
  --cost-function-param arg (=0) Specify the parameter of the cost function. Implemented is "C" only for now.
```

Does someone have an explanation? Thanks!

Comment: Please translate to English

Comment: It is shocking, but most of the inhabitants of the planet (more than 90%) don't understand French. You need to translate your question to English. (C'est choquant, mais la plupart des habitants du planète (plus que 90%) ne comprends pas le français. Il faut que tu traduises ta question en anglais.)

Comment: I will change that. However, I don't see how I can modify that yet. 
Ok it is done. Thanks for your remark.

Comment: Please post minimal example that compiles and exhibits the issue

Comment: I have added an example.

Comment: Nope, not seeing a problem when running this.

Comment: My g++ compiler version is 4.7.4. Could this be it?

Comment: There are [ancient closed tickets](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/860) on this. What boost version are you using?

Comment: You are right I guess. I have a 10 year old version. I cannot update it myself though. Great..... Thank you anyway!